# View click not recognized?

Tags: android

My button click does not get recognized. Actually, no clicks get recognized at all.

Here is my activity:

```
public class ShowRecieveActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @BindView(R.id.copy_button)
    Button button;

    //oncreate and all other methods....

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Timber.d("Click detected");
        if(v.getId() == R.id.copy_button){
            Timber.d("Click detected as copy button");
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Wallet address", wallet.getAddress());
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Timber.d("Clip set as: "+clipboard.getPrimaryClip().toString());

            showToast("Address copied to clipboard");
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow clicks in this activity do not get recognized at all. `BaseActivity` only implements `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` and that's it.

Does this interfere somehow with this `view.onclicklistener`? It shouldn't, right? What could the problem be?

If you need more from my code, let me know please.

Comment: Seeing that you are using ButterKnife to bind your clicks but some of the code I believe is missing. For starters, have you implemented ButterKnife.bind(this) in your onCreate method? Secondly, how are you relating your click method to the button? You would need to add the event click listener to recognize the trigger.

Comment: @Nero Yes, I do call Butter.bind(this). What do you mean by relating my click method to the button?

Comment: i think you are missing `button.setOnClickListener(this)`inside onCreate() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this - 

The way which you've applied so far:

```
@BindView(R.id.copy_button)
Button button;

//onCreate method
button.setOnClickListener()... and so on...
```

However, this method doesn't justify the use of ButterKnife as you are using the default method of doing this but replacing the wiring process in the onCreate method.
It's only useful when you want to access elements easily i.e. textview, edittext and so on..

But to answer the question, you should be using the following method:

```
@OnClick(R.id.click_button) 
public void buttonClick(View view) { 
    Timber.d("Click detected");
    if(v.getId() == R.id.copy_button){
        Timber.d("Click detected as copy button");
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Wallet address", wallet.getAddress());
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        Timber.d("Clip set as: "+clipboard.getPrimaryClip().toString());

        showToast("Address copied to clipboard");
    }
}
```

Via this method, you are creating a link button the button which should listen to the event when triggered.

Answer (score 2):

I not sure about this but I think you're not using butterknife correctly.

if you just binding button for clicking, you don't need to use `@BindView`, use `@Onclick(R.id.copy_button)`

```
@OnClick(R.id.copy_button)
public void submit(View view) {
  // TODO submit data to server...
}
```

based on [butterknife official website](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an `ClickListener` to you `button`, add this code after `Butter.bind(this)` inside onCreate method :

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Using butter knife looks like this line

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

that makes the real bind of all your views (make sure to put it on onCreate method before using views).